# Are there any known problems using GPS connection in Android version of QGIS?

Tags: qgis, gps, android, windows

I install QGIS both my netbook (windows win7 starter) and My tablet (android 4.0). I can used GPS option in windows version and I can save location points from GPS. However, I could not manage same operation in android verion of QGIS. Is there any problem on android version?

Comment: Please keep in mind that the android version is still only very new.

Comment: I think you would get more feedback to this question on the mailing list or from the developer himself.

Comment: Android location API is probably not integrated there yet. Did you would try to install gpsd to the tablet? This may be able to bridge QGIS and Android GPS.